# Arduino Scara Robot inverse kinematics

Tags: arduino, inverse-kinematics

I am building a simple scara robot using an Arduino Uno with a CNC shield and for that, I programmed a simple library (Here a normal program for testing purposes). I keep getting back NaN so not a number where is my mistake?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <Arduino.h>

#define conversionJoints 3; //1:3
#define Microstepping 16

const double L1 = 246.5;
const double L2 = 160;

float alpha = 0; // radians
float beta = 0;

float alpha_d; //degrees
float beta_d;

float input_angle;
float output_steps;

float convert(float input_angle){
  if(input_angle == 0){
    input_angle = 18;
    output_steps = (200*Microstepping)/(360/(input_angle*2))*conversionJoints;
    delay(10);
    output_steps -= 960;
    input_angle -= 18;
    return output_steps;
  }else{
    output_steps = (200*Microstepping)/(360/(input_angle*2))*conversionJoints;
    return output_steps;
  }
}

float calc_IK_beta(float x, float y){
  beta = acos((x*x+y*y-L1*L1-L2*L2)/(2*L1*L2));
  beta_d = beta * 180 / M_PI;

  if(x < 0 && y > 0){
    beta_d = beta_d - (2*beta_d);
  }else if(x < 0 && y < 0){
    beta_d = beta_d - 2*beta_d - 90;
  }else if(x > 0 && y < 0){
    beta_d = beta_d - beta_d*2;
  }

  return convert(beta_d);
}

float calc_IK_alpha(float x, float y){
  beta = acos((x*x+y*y-L1*L1-L2*L2)/(2*L1*L2));
  beta_d = beta * 180 / M_PI;

  alpha_d = (atan((atan((L2*sin(beta))/(L1+L2*cos(beta)))*180/M_PI - y/x))*180/M_PI);

  if(x < 0 && y > 0){
    alpha_d = alpha_d - 2*alpha_d;
  }else if(x < 0 && y < 0){
    alpha_d = alpha_d - 2*alpha_d - 90;
  }else if(x > 0 && y < 0){
    alpha_d = alpha_d - 90;
  }
  
  return convert(alpha_d);
}

void setup(){
  float x = 10;
  float y = 10;

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(calc_IK_alpha(x,y));
  Serial.print(calc_IK_beta(x,y));
}

void loop(){

}
```

I want to use these equations:
[image]

Comment: please copy the full error message and paste into your question abd format as code ... NO screenshots please

Comment: I have no error message. The serial monitor just prints nan twice.

Comment: from which line? ... add debug code to determine where the error originates

Comment: From these two lines:
  ´Serial.println(calc_IK_alpha(x,y));
  Serial.print(calc_IK_beta(x,y));´
i would expect to get two numbers but instead both just return nan.

Comment: as I said before ... write debug code to determine where the problem occurs... the two `Serial.print` lines are  debug code ... add more

Comment: Please use Mathjax, rather than screenshots of equations